# Too scared to give resignation

Tags: professionalism, job-offer, new-job, career-switch

I recently joined an organisation, and after a month I decided to quit gracefully, as I feel it's not a good fit for me. I have been a very genuine person and have never done this before, hence I have some fear discussing these things with my manager.

Since my immediate manager is on leave, I gathered some courage to talk to his manager (i.e. very senior manager), but as we started our discussion I started choking. I told him what I feel about this workplace and had to leave my previous organisation because of the same reason. He listened to me carefully, gave some advice, and told me to discuss things with my immediate manager who would return next week. The main thing is I know that things are never going to change, but I didn't have the courage to say I want to quit before his face as it felt rude to me.

The issue is I can't wait until Monday for discussion as I want to serve proper notice period and time is a constraint for me, because I have another offer which has been waiting for me for month. I will try to push them for another month but fear they won't and then I would have hardly 15 days to join them.

So, coming to my question: should I send a formal mail without waiting for my manager? Is that a rude behaviour? Did I do the right thing by not resigning in the first meeting?

Comment: You should write to *your* manager an email ASAP. You may have done the right thing by not resigning to your manager's boss, as this things should be done with your superior (chain of command).

Comment: @GrayCygnus: chain of command? He is leaving so there is no such chain IMHO

Comment: "He is leaving" in what way? Is he also resigning? If that is the case, until the moment he actually resigns he is still your boss, so the chain of command still could apply.

Comment: @CrayCygnus: I don't agree. This is about him leaving. It is not about job duties

Comment: There are a lot of things (too many) going on in this question - [resigning when your boss is on leave](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/61947/want-to-resign-but-bosses-are-out-of-office-today), [resigning from a new job](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7149/how-can-one-resign-from-a-new-job-gracefully) and being too scared to resign - not sure this would be the right place to get help on that last one though.

Comment: @CrayCygnus: yes he is resigning. What do you mean by that?

Comment: @smith As long as OP is an employee, he has a boss, your disagreement notwithstanding. CrayCygnus is right. The goal of leaving gracefully is about not screwing things up during the resignation process.

Comment: Also, the OP mentions that he wants to quit this job "because it's not a good fit" and that he also left his previous job for the same reason.  Perhaps the issue is not so much this job, but the OP's inability to feel comfortable in a new workplace?  Perhaps the entire industry he's in is a "bad fit" and he should consider changing careers, or perhaps he just needs advice on how to get over the "new job jitters" so he can begin to feel like he fits in just fine.

Comment: You've had another offer waiting for a month, and you've worked for your current job for a month? Have you been leaving the other place hanging as a backup plan since you started? Do you really think it's helpful of you to work there for a month or two? There's so much that's confusing about this.

Comment: This doesn't answer your main question, but as someone who also has trouble discussing some subjects I've learned that the best way to handle it, is just to blurt it out. By starting the discussion at any other point, you are giving yourself excuses to not have to say it, but really what's holding you back is just the fear. I quit a little over a month ago, and I did it by making "I'm resigning" the first sentence of the meeting, because I worried about doing precisely the same thing.

Comment: Since you have quit two jobs within a month each for the same reason, I am curious to know why you see these jobs as "not a good fit". Perhaps we could try to help you with *that*.

Comment: @Steve-O you seem highly stereotyped overall, I have 6 years of experience in which I was in the last organisation for 4 years and won several excellence award there, it was my hunger for learning that motivated me to check for new challenges and if the new company offers the same environment then what's good for me there? I could have remained in my last organisation where I earned a lot of respect.

Comment: @MaskedMan read my comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't particularly care about this job or your manager, and don't intend to list it on your resume, you're free to give notice by email and simply walk away (assuming you have no specific additional contractual obligations).

If you do want to list this job on your resume, and ask your manager for a reference, the best thing to do would be to resign in person. If the worst thing is you have to wait a few more days to give notice, that doesn't seem to be much of a burden.

Comment: I don't think I would like to show a month of experience anywhere.

Comment: @johndoe: his point is, do you care if you leave on good terms or not?

Comment: Of course I want to leave on good terms but without affecting my future employment, hope you got the point.

Comment: @johndoe: you there for what 1month? Do they depend some project on you? Would your leave cause any disrupt? Is your immediate manager the reason you leave? If not then I don't really think that for this case your immediate manager would really care... my 2 cents

Comment: yes, 1 month. project dependency not exactly I just got started and pushed couple of commits, its not my manager but overall environment.

Comment: @johndoe: that other company offered you a position? And you have been postponing the starting day for 1month with what excuse? Why didn't you give your notice as soon as you made a deal with the other company?

Comment: @smith its better to say no before joining rather than after joining.

Comment: @johndoe:I didn't understand. Do you have a specific contract offer for a position to the other company or not?

Comment: @smith I have another offer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the place and have an offer, unless you have signed that you need to resign specifically to your immediate manager then just submit your resignation.
It all depends what you have signed. Read your contract terms and aski HR if in doubt. If there is no such formal obligation just quit regardless of when your immediate manager is back.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I personally feel any job which gives us dissatisfaction we should move on. This is a strong reason which I feel your manager will understand. As I feel if a person is doing his job just for the sake of doing he will never give the productivity which company wants. Moreover you can also express him why you are dissatisfaction and which cannot be improved in here.

Secondly, as you said you are already having an offer where you can proceed just make sure new company you are looking ahead is worth your satisfaction.